# How do I print this without quotation marks and brackets in Python?

Tags: python, json

This is my code

```
keys = {"setup", "punchline"}

l = [{k:v for k, v in i.items() if k in keys} for i in response_dict]


print(json.dumps(l, indent=4, sort_keys=False))
```

```
    {
        "setup": "What's the best part about TCP jokes?",
        "punchline": "I get to keep telling them until you get them."
    },
    {
        "setup": "How many programmers does it take to change a lightbulb?",
        "punchline": "None that's a hardware problem"
    },
    {
        "setup": "What's the best thing about a Boolean?",
        "punchline": "Even if you're wrong, you're only off by a bit."
```

Deisred output
setup:  What's the best part about TCP jokes?
punchline: I get to keep telling them until you get them.

Comment: do you want to print out the 'setup' and 'punchline' as well or just the sentences ?

Comment: Please include the desired output.

Comment: Please add more details in the question. How do you want your output to look like?

Comment: yes, I want to print the setup and punchline

Comment: If you don't want quotation marks and brackets, what are you converting it to JSON for? Maybe... *don't* do that?

Comment: am a beginner can you help

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Here are the ingredients which will help you to accomplish this task:

- knowing [how to access dictionary attributes by keys](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)
- [print](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function
- `for` loop to loop through the list `l`.

Think about how you would output a single joke in `l[0]`. What's inside of `l[0]['setup']` and what's inside of `l[0]['punchline']`?